# Is there a way to save current state of network configuration in linux into a datafile or set of ip commands like iptables-save?

Tags: linux, centos, iproute, systemd-networkd

Let's say I ran quite a few ip commands and ended up with a required network configuration, but I didn't save the command history.

Instead of rewriting commands in a file or script again, is there a way to dump/save the state of network configuration like iptables-save or mysqldump and so, later we can restore?

I see similar thing is possible with `netnsh` in windows (not sure if it's exactly the kind of solution I am looking for..havne't gone through it, but it seems like it dumps the network configuration state).

But I can't find any option in Linux (especially CentOS/RHEL)

Comment: Doesn't iptables-save work at all?

Comment: iptables-save working for saving iptable rules. I am looking for a similar way to save network configuration. However, I can think of some reasons why it may not be possible to save network configuration entirely, as if a physical interface is missing at the time of restore, few configurations may fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some support does exist for saving addresses, routes and rules, using iproute2's `ip` command.

For obvious reason, this doesn't exist for links, even if one could imagine the possibility to save *some* virtual links, not all ("saving" a single side of a veth-pair link with its peer accross an other network namespace? not gonna happen...), or being able to save a bridge's and bridge's ports configurations including vlan etc., this doesn't appear to exist currently.

Existing commands are:

```
ip address save
ip address restore
ip route save
ip route restore
ip rule save
ip rule restore
```

The dump format is binary and the commands will refuse to save to or restore from a tty.

I suggest restoring addresses before routes (rules can be done at any order), or most saved routes won't be restored because they can't satisfy routing conditions depending on addresses. Warning: of course all flush commands below will likely disrupt network connectivity until the restore is done, so this should be avoided from remote network access (or be done in other network namespaces).

- `ip address save` / `ip address restore`

  So to copy addresses from a simple network namespace `orig`'s configuration having a `dummy0` interface (to keep the example simple) to a namespace `copy`:

  ```
  ip netns add orig
  ip netns exec orig sh << 'EOF'
  ip link add dummy0 type dummy
  ip address add dev dummy0 192.0.2.2/24
  ip address add dev dummy0 2001:db8:0:1::2/64
  ip link set dummy0 up
  ip address save > /tmp/address
  EOF

  ip netns add copy
  ip netns exec copy sh << 'EOF'
  ip link add dummy0 type dummy
  ip link set dummy0 up
  ip address restore < /tmp/address
  ip -br address
  EOF
  ```

  will give for example this result:

  ```
  lo               DOWN           
  dummy0           UNKNOWN        192.0.2.2/24 2001:db8:0:1::2/64 fe80::68e3:bdff:feb0:6e85/64 fe80::e823:d1ff:fe8c:3a15/64
  ```

  Note: that previous automatic IPv6 link-local (`scope link`) address was also saved, and is thus restored, leading to an additional (and wrong) IPv6 link-local address, because the link/ether address (here in `orig` `6a:e3:bd:b0:6e:85`) on which is based the IPv6 link-local address is not saved and thus not restored (leaving here the in `copy` the other random MAC `ea:23:d1:8c:3a:15` on `dummy0`). So care should actually be done to separately save and copy the MAC address of such virtual interfaces if it really matters, or prune after some addresses for physical interfaces.

  You should probably flush all addresses before restoring them to avoid leaving old ones if the environment wasn't a "clean slate". Contrary to routes below, I couldn't find a simple way to flush all of them in *one* command without having to state an interface. Using those *two* should be good enough:

  ```
  ip address flush permanent
  ip address flush temporary
  ```

On the same principle, routes and rules can be saved and restored:

- `ip route save` / `ip route restore`

  There's a trick. `ip route save` will save only the `main` table, which is good for common use cases, but not with policy routing's additional routing tables. You can state a specific table (eg `ip rule save table 220`) if needed. But the special `table 0` represents *all* tables, using `ip route save table 0` will save *all* of them (including for each route the table it belongs to, like would be displayed with `ip route show table 0`) at once. Before restoring routes, it should be preferable to flush all existing routes:

  ```
  ip route flush table 0 all
  ```

  Example showing any routing table can be saved without having to know its value beforehand:

  ```
  # ip route add table 220 unreachable 10.0.0.0/8 metric 9999
  # ip route show table 220
  unreachable 10.0.0.0/8 metric 9999 
  # ip route save table 0 > /tmp/route
  # ip route flush table 0 all
  # ip route show table 220
  #
  # ip route restore table 0 < /tmp/route
  # ip route show table 220
  unreachable 10.0.0.0/8 metric 9999
  ```

  Of course all routes from other tables, including table 254 aka `main`, are also saved and restored.
- `ip rule save` / `ip rule restore`

  This one is also tricky because if not flushed before it will add duplicates without complaining, and flushing the rules never flushes rule prio 0, so `rule priority 0` has to be explicitly deleted:

  ```
  ip rule flush
  ip rule delete priority 0
  ```

  So to save and restore:

  ```
  ip rule save > /tmp/rule
  ```

  [...] just deleting, or switching to some other environment etc.

  ```
  ip rule flush
  ip rule delete priority 0
  ip rule restore < /tmp/rule
  ```

I hope you can find some usage of this, for example for automatization with multiple network namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer :) I actually wanted to restore the links too, as I did create few namespaces, bridges and veth links. But I have also realized with all the complexity, it's a good idea to reconfigure manually or with scripts than trying to restore.:)

Comment: good stuff... call it covid-fog but I want to connect it to systemd.  :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a script in this [github](https://github.com/raszia/save_network_configuration) repository. by this script you can save your current network configuration commands to a bash script.

`./save_my_network.py`

After executing this script you can find a `network.save` file in your current directory

```
cat network.save

#!/bin/bash
ip addr add 192.168.1.97/24 dev wlan0
echo 0x1003 > /sys/class/net/wlan0/flags
ip addr add 172.17.0.1/16 dev docker0
ip addr add 172.19.0.1/24 dev docker0
ip addr add 172.18.0.1/24 dev docker0
ip addr add 172.20.0.1/16 dev docker0
echo 0x1002 > /sys/class/net/docker0/flags
ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
echo 0x9 > /sys/class/net/lo/flags
ip addr add 10.8.0.15/24 dev tun0
echo 0x1091 > /sys/class/net/tun0/flags
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.15 
ip route add 94.130.24.225 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.97 metric 600
```

Don't forget execute permission for `network.save`

`chmod +x network.save`

Answer (score 0):

Your network configuration should be saved in files such as /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifconfig-(interface) and /etc/sysconfig/network, /etc/resolv.conf, etc.  You should just modify these files and restart your network service rather then making your changes on the fly.  Any changes you make on the fly, like route or IP changes, will be lost when your system restarts.

Comment: Hi.. yes, I know the use of the config files.but I'm checking if it's possible to generate config files or a restoration script automatically from the current state.. anyhow I think it's a dead end :|